# Android device :elocity A7 040 not detected

Tags: android, adb

I am trying to develop on an android tablet : elocity A7 040. I cannot find the device through adb once I connect it using the USB cable provided along. 
I have already done the following

1)USB debugging on

2)The application has android:debuggable="true"

3)I am developing on OSX 10.6.8, so I believe I don't require any USB drivers. It should work according to http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html

Note: I don't see any message on the notification bar, once I connect the usb cable. So I don't have the obvious choice ( given once I connect my motorola milestone ) of changing USB options.

Thanks

Comment: Check with the manufacturer for a usb id. Even on OSX which picks up most devices, the Kindle Fire is not picked up and 0x1949 must be added to ~/.android/adb_usb.ini

Answer (score 0):

You should have done at least two things to get your device recognized:

1. specify USB manufacturer and device ID in your hot-plug manager
2. add an entry to ~/.android/adb_usb.ini, as Chuck mentioned before

You may find manufacturer and device IDs with 'lsusb' command (that's LSUSB in lower case). If your system does not have this command, borrow someone's Linux computer for a minute.